# How to remake an angular workspace with specific and exaclty packages versions?

Tags: angular, package.json

I´m trying to remake an Angular Workspace including my library project and a test application using Angular 11 but if I´ve installed `@angular/cli@v11.0.0` when I run

> ng new my-workspace-v11 --create-application false

I got this **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-workspace-v11",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

And I got an error with jasmine-core.
So, as I´m using this library for specific angular projects and I need that works for them,
I would like to get a workspace with :

```
...
"@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^11.0.3",
...
```

And do something to avoid any conflict of packages.
What is the process to do that ?

Even if I ask all exactly versions of a specific angular projet which is running on production server, I got building error.

I tried this :

```
{
  "name": "my-workspace-v11",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.16",
    "@types/node": "8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.1",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.15.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I got this :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: nua-workspace-v11@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@6.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"6.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.5.3" from @angular/core@11.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"11.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"11.0.3" from @angular/animations@11.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"11.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

How is it possible ?

Comment: To install and re-create the exact same dependencies tree from another project, you have to copy the `package-lock.json` file as well and then run `npm i`. You don't need to run `ng new`.

Comment: @NeluB, I´m not trying to reinstall a project, I´m trying to make new workspace to test my library but with specific versions of packages so I don´t have a package-lock.json for this workspace. I just have package.json and package-lock.json from projects that are running in production server.

Comment: While you're on it, I'd suggest that you create an [NX workspace](https://nx.dev/). It supports many feature that an angular workspace is unable to cope with, such as referencing a library from another library, and many more. It's the recommended approach to build **monorepos**

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the project you're trying to replicate has the version you're looking for exactly, watching for minor and patch versions

```
"@angular/core": "11.0.3"
vs
"@angular/core": "^11.0.3"
```

It's possible that the installed versions will differ from what you're expecting because of the `^`

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be when you use a npm@7.x.x or superior
(I´m using npm@8.1.0), peer dependencies can block the install process. These versions are more strict.
To avoid that problem, the command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` makes the job.

In my case, the project using my library was built with a npm 6.x.x, that´s why some package incompatibilties was accepted before and not now.